# Get or Create Functionality on a Writable Nested Serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Suppose I have the following models:

```
Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('User')
    ...

User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
    ...
```

*Note: `USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'`.*

When a new order is created, I would like to link it to a customer with the supplied email, or create the customer if the they do not exist already.

---

This is what I've tried so far:

**serializers.py:**

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    customer = UserSerializer(many=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Order

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user_data = validated_data.pop('user')

        # Get or create a User
        user, created = User.objects.get_or_create(
            email=user_data['email'],
            defaults={
                'email': user_data['email']
            }
        )
        order = Order.objects.create(user=user, **validated_data)
        return order
```

The problem is, if a User exists, I get a 400 "Email already exists" error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, I had to disable the unique validators on a `User`. This seemed like a bad idea considering that I would need those validators when creating Users from a different endpoint.

`email` had to be unique and the nested serializer runs the valdiation from the UserSerializer.

Instead, I created another serializer called `OrderUserSerializer` as follows:

**serializers.py**:

```
class OrderUserSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField(max_length=200)


class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = OrderUserSerializer(many=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Order

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user_data = validated_data.pop('user')

        user, created = User.objects.get_or_create(
            email=user_data['email'],
            defaults={
                'email': user_data['email']
            }
        )

        order = Order.objects.create(user=user, **validated_data)
        return order
```